# How to set a div percentage width with a fixed position based on the parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, scroll, width

I'm working on Wordpress and I need to make a div fixed on the top when the page is scrolled. The div (*.details*) must have a percentage width for responsive reasons. I found a javascript to stop the div (*.details*) when it is 40px from the top, switching it from a relative position to a fixed one. It has a 25% width when in relative position, but when it become fixed, the 25% width is now based on the window and it isn't based on the parent element (*.entry*), that is smaller than the window, so it become larger when I scroll. These are the CSS and the Javascript (*.carousel* is the other div inside *.entry*, it's on the left of .details):

```
<style>
.entry { position:relative; width:100%; }
.carousel { width:70%; height: auto; position: relative; float: left; margin-top: 0px;}
.details { width: 25px; height: 100%; float: right; margin-top: 0px; line-height: 20px;} 
</style>

<script>
$(window).scroll(function(){
if  ($(window).scrollTop() >= 90){
     $('.details').css({position:'fixed',right:40,top:40,width:'25%'});
} else {
     $('.details').css({position:'relative',right:0,top:0,width:'25%'});
    }
});
</script>
```

I need to make the width of .details div based on .entry and not on the window.
Anyone can find mistakes or need something else? I'm not a pro in Javascript.
Thank you all!

Comment: There is no way to make a fixed element relative to it's parent. It will always be relative to the window. You could set the width using JavaScript, but then you would have to attach an event listener window size change

Comment: You should create a JSFiddle or give us a link to an example. Is there a reason you don't want your menu 100% width of the window?

Comment: This is the website: http://www.davidegiorgetta.com/choos/. As you can see there is a text box on the right (.details). When you scroll the page it become larger. The box is not 100% because there is another box (.carousel) on the left for the images. I'm going to prepare the fiddle. I hope I'm clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to do this is by setting the `.details` width with JavaScript. Try this:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop() >= 90){
        $('.details').css({position:'fixed',right:40,top:40});
    } else {
        $('.details').css({position:'relative',right:0,top:0});
    }
});


// set the width of the details div when window resizes
window.addEventListener('resize', function(){

    var $el = $('.details')

    $el.width( $el.parent().outerWidth() * .25 )

})
```

#### Here's a [crude example](http://jsfiddle.net/RAWKm/)

Comment: It's a perfect solution! I tried to use it in jsfiddle and on a blanck web page and it works. But when I put it in Wordpress it doesn't. maybe is for a conflict with jQuery. This is the right solution, do you have advices to solve the conflict problem? Thank you!

Comment: try looking at the JavaScript console and tell me what it says.

Comment: I hope I checked in the right place (on Chrome > element inspector > console) This is what it says:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < www.davidegiorgetta.com/choos/:207
Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Object] is not a function www.davidegiorgetta.com/choos/:220
Failed to load resource http://127.0.0.1:4001/isrunning
3459

Comment: and this: 
Blocked a frame with origin "http://www.davidegiorgetta.com" from accessing a frame with origin "chrome-extension://oknpjjbmpnndlpmnhmekjpocelpnlfdi".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "http", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "chrome-extension". Protocols must match.
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://www.davidegiorgetta.com/Pronto-child/style.css

Comment: Blocked a frame with origin "http://www.davidegiorgetta.com" from accessing a frame with origin "chrome-extension://oknpjjbmpnndlpmnhmekjpocelpnlfdi".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "http", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "chrome-extension". Protocols must match.
Blocked a frame with origin "http://www.davidegiorgetta.com" from accessing a frame with origin "chrome-extension://oknpjjbmpnndlpmnhmekjpocelpnlfdi".

Comment: The frame requesting access has a protocol of "http", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "chrome-extension". Protocols must match.
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Blocked a frame with origin "http://www.davidegiorgetta.com" from accessing a frame with origin "chrome-extension://oknpjjbmpnndlpmnhmekjpocelpnlfdi".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "http", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "chrome-extension". Protocols must match.Blocked a frame with origin "http://www.davidegiorgetta.com" from accessing a frame with origin "chrome-extension://oknpjjbmpnndlpmnhmekjpocelpnlfdi".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "http", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "chrome-extension". Protocols must match.

Comment: That's all. There are a lot of errors. I hope you can find the jquery one. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Looks like you have a paragraph tag inside of your `<script>` tag on line 195: [Screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/v2KwDdj.png)

Comment: Wordpress automatically put the paragraphs on the script! Ok, I solved now. But it doesn't work neither now! In any case thank you for the advice!

Comment: Ok, it finally works!!! Just a few automatic paragraphs in the wrong position! Thanks a lot Kevin Jantzer!